# How to sort strings with special characters in Hibernate?

Tags: sorting, hibernate

For example, if the Order in criteria is ascending and if we have two names like follows:

- _zname_9
- 1_aname_

I get an output (from hibernate result) like:

- _zname_9
- 1_aname_

But the expected output (java sorting) is:

- 1_aname_
- _zname_9

Am I missing something? Please note that I dont want to escape special characters while setting the criteria.

Can we mention regarding special characters while sorting?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert when it comes to collations but the following does provide the sorting your require. It may cause other characters to be sorted unexpectedly so please test.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  '_zname_9' AS SortVal
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '1_aname_' AS SortVal
)

SELECT  *

FROM    cte 

--ORDER BY  SortVal
ORDER BY SortVal COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN2
```

I've used a BIN2 collation to cover that fact that your `name` column may be a  unicode data type.